# Amazon DynamoDB Group by emulation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am a little but confusing about Amazon DynamoDB. 
I would like to use group by some attributes on a table (number of users who are using a certain game, i.e.) but, as Dynamo hasn't the "group by" concept, I really do not know how to aggregate rows.
How can I emulate the "group by" behavior without using Amazon EMR?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have `group by` in DynamoDb

Comment: ok, I understand that is not possibile grouping directly on DynamoDB, but I think there will be some workaround, but how?

Comment: One way is to download the data to your client and then perform the aggregation locally.

Comment: If the data you need to group is small you can retrieve it all.  DynamoDB is not meant to hold normalize data (but it can be costly).  You should create the tables to match the way the data will be displayed.  If you need aggregation, you need to compute the aggregation upfront and then put the result in DynamoDB.  DynamoDB is a key/value store with some lite extra functionality, if you need more functionality ask you self back if a classical DB can do the job.

Comment: @Kazaag- that is actually an answer to this question. why put it as a comment?!